# Extract values from Ajax call with XML type in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, xml-parsing, asp.net-ajax

**In PHP**, I can call a page like this

```
var data = {
    type: 'simple_data'

};

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/haha.php',  //load data 

    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: loading_complete,
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

And in the PHP server side page, we catch it like

```
$type=$_POST['type'];
```

Pretty simple right! It gives back the XML info and GOAL.

Now I want to do it for ASP.NET pages in same way as PHP. I want to call the ASP.NET page like

```
var data = {
    type: 'simple_data'

};

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/haha.aspx',  //load data 

    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: loading_complete,
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

So how can I catch the data and extract values in ASP.NET. That means I want the functionality similar to this '$_POST['type']' in ASP.NET. I tried to search but nothing found yet or may be didn't find in the right direction. **Can anyone please tell me how can I extract this data from this ajax call with XML??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Request.Form["type"]`

Comment: Great. Small, Sweet and simple. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. You need to pass the method name in your URL parameter like so:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/haha.aspx/MethodName',  //load data 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: loading_complete,
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
});
```

ASP.Net will know how to handle the web request and parse the data. You can write something on the .aspx page as simple as:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MethodName(string type)
{
    // do work with type
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to keep the MethodName function Static?? I can't make my own method static due to some other dependencies. And this technique is not working for me though it looks good. The AJAX call isn't working with the MethodName.